# How to search for text in an xml file and change it using qml?

Tags: xml, qml

I am trying to write an application for Ubuntu touch which uses QML.  What I am trying to do right now is search an xml file and change the text.

this is my XML file:

```
<phonelist>
  <phone>
    <name>drewphone</name>
    <lost>no</lost>
  </phone>
  <phone>
    <name>sarahpone</name>
    <lost>yes</lost>
  </phone>
</phonelist>
```

I want to search for sarahphone or drewphone and then change lost to either yes or no.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: And why would you do this using QML? QML is not a general-purpose language.

Comment: I'm trying to develop for Ubuntu Touch and the developers site recommends QML

Answer (score 2):

Since QML has no file I/O I am curious as to how you are actually reading this file in the first place.

Assuming you are getting this XML from an XMLHttpRequest, it sounds like you want to do this manipulation in javascript.  Since javascript is not designed with data manipulation tasks in mind the only library you have access to that could help you would be the string manipulation library.  If you really do not want to write C++(where you would have access to actual XML parser libraries), AND your xml stays very simple you may be able to use regex to find and replace the appropriate text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm trying to figure out how to program for Ubuntu Touch and the only languages I have learnt so far are Java, C and a little C++ so I'm just trying to find my way around XML and QML

Comment: @Sarah QML isn't a substitute for Java, C or C++, its purpose is to help you defining your application UI in the smartest, easiest, and fastest possible way. As I said above, it isn't a general purpose language like the other three mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XSLT to transform XML into QML.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: I don't really understand how that converts to qml?

Answer (score 0):

QML has `XmlListModel` which is used to create **a read-only model** from XML data. It can be used as a data source for **view elements (such as ListView, PathView, GridView) and other elements** that interact with model data (such as Repeater)[reference : [XmlListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html#details)].

The best way to do it (i.e : manipulate XML) is to create a **helper class** in c++ (c++ side of Qt has good XML library [Qt XML C++ Classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html)) which fulfill the job and later access its functions (or whatever) in qml by using `QQmlContext::setContextProperty(const QString &name, QObject *value)`. For an easy and illustrative example read this paragraph "**Setting an Object as a Context Property**": [Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html).